# Why are modules showing up as themes?

Tags: commerce

I am uploading my Drupal Commerce Kickstart website to the host from my local computer, and I seem to be facing issues at every turn. I have not edited any of the code (trying to avoid it) or moved around any folders except in themes so it's likely something to do with that.

It does not seem to be affecting the functionality of the website but clearly I've moved (or not properly uploaded via FTP) something important. I searched through as best I could and haven't found anyone else who has broken Drupal like this so I'm feeling pretty special.

Why are modules showing up as themes?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think we'll need a bit more details on your problem to be able to help. When you say your modules are showing up as themes, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean quite literally my Module list is duplicated in my Appearance panel as if they are all installed themes! Here is a screenshot: http://i62.tinypic.com/svt2cw.jpg

Comment: Can you show a tree of your sites folder?

Answer (score 7):

Drupal uses a function called [_system_rebuild_theme_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/_system_rebuild_theme_data/7) to help determine the list of themes (both enabled and disabled) to show on that page. That function does a number of things, but the first thing it does is to look for any .info files within the "themes" directories, which can include /themes, /sites/all/themes, sites/anydirectory/themes.

So, based on the screenshot, it appears that you have some modules placed in a themes directory. I would go through your themes directories to make sure that that isn't the case.

Comment: Bingo. Stemming from the bizarre organization of Commerce Kickstart. I upgraded and broke everything, but was able to fix by moving the kickstart theme into the sites folder - Kickstart is nice for a fast build but not the most friendly for upgrades, it seems... This is awesome though, thank you!